# How to export font's family as english

Tags: javascript, localization, photoshop, photoshop-script

I have the following photoshop script:

```
var myFont = app.fonts.getByName("STHeitiSC-Light");

alert(msyfont.family);// alert   "黑体-简"
```

But  I want get `Heiti SC`? i.e. in english

I use the Chinese version of photoshop.

Comment: Just out of interest what happens when you get the Post Script Name?    var myFont = app.fonts.getByName("Arial-BoldMT");     var myPSFont = myFont.postScriptName; alert(myFont.name); // Arial Bold; alert(myPSFont);  // Arial-BoldMT

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can get an alternate family name because this property is stored **inside the font file**. It's not determined by Photoshop, the software only reads the information contained in the file.

Since your Photoshop is in Chinese, so must be font families packed with it. Your only options would be to get rid of these fonts and install their English versions; or edit each font file, switching their Chinese names for their English counterparts.